# Find position of button inside listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a List view that I fill the rows via mysql database.

This is a view of what I have done:

[image]

This names that you saw are coming from my database and the **PLAY** ImageView is from my layout list that appears in each row(when I add a name into my database).

Now my problem is when I set a click listener to that play button, (*purpose is switching it into pause ImageView and etc.*) It changes another play buttons from another rows too,but not all of  them. Hence I think I'm not getting the position, right? Can you help me with this please!

**This is my Fragment :**

```
public class XXXUpdatesFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse
,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    View view ;
    private ArrayList<Product> productList;
    private ListView lvProduct;
    private FunDapter<Product> adapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx_updates_layout, container, false);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(getActivity()));

        lvProduct = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);

        PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(getActivity(), this);

        taskRead.execute("http://symphonyrecords.6te.net/product.php");

        return view;
    } //onCreate


    @Override
    public void  processFinish(String s) {
        productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);

        BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
        dict.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
                return product.name;
            }
        });

        dict.addStringField(R.id.tvDescription, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
                return product.description;   
            }
        });

        dict.addStringField(R.id.tvQty, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
                return "" + product.qty;
            }
        });


        adapter = new FunDapter<>(getActivity(), productList, R.layout.d_layout_list_d, dict);


        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Product selectedProduct = productList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),selectedProduct.name+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }


    }
```

**This is my Product class :**

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("pid")
public int pid;

@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

@SerializedName("qty")
public int qty;

@SerializedName("price")
public String description;
}
```

**And this is my Adapter :**

```
public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {



private boolean paused = true;


protected List<T> mDataItems;
protected List<T> mOrigDataItems;
protected LongExtractor<T> idExtractor;
protected final Context mContext;
private final int mLayoutResource;
private final BindDictionary<T> mBindDictionary;
private int oddColorRes;
private int evenColorRes;
private FunDapterFilter<T> funDapterFilter;
private Filter mFilter;


public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
  this(context, dataItems, layoutResource, null, dictionary);
}

public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 LongExtractor<T> idExtractor, BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mLayoutResource = layoutResource;
    this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
    this.mBindDictionary = dictionary;

}

public void updateData(List<T> dataItems) {
    this.mDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mDataItems == null || mBindDictionary == null) return 0;

    return mDataItems.size();
}

@Override
public T getItem(int position) {
    return mDataItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    if(idExtractor == null) return super.hasStableIds();
    else return true;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if(idExtractor == null) return position;
    else return idExtractor.getLongValue(getItem(position), position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final GenericViewHolder holder;
    if (null == v) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
        holder = new GenericViewHolder();
        holder.root = v;


        holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
        holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        if (paused) {
                            holder.playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                            paused=false;
                        }
                        else {
                            paused = true;
                            holder.playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                        }

            }});



        FunDapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);

        v.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    final T item = getItem(position);
    showData(item, holder, position);

    return v;
}


private void showData(T item, GenericViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (oddColorRes > 0 && evenColorRes > 0) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.root.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(evenColorRes));
        } else {
            holder.root.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(oddColorRes));
        }
    }

    FunDapterUtils.showData(item, holder, position, mBindDictionary);
}

public FunDapter<T> setAlternatingBackground(int oddColorRes, int evenColorRes) {

    if (oddColorRes <= 0 || evenColorRes <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Color parameters are illegal");
    }

    this.oddColorRes = oddColorRes;
    this.evenColorRes = evenColorRes;

    return this;
}

public void setIdExtractor(LongExtractor<T> idExtractor) {
    this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

public void initFilter(FunDapterFilter<T> filter) {

    if (filter == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot pass a null filter to FunDapter");

    this.funDapterFilter = filter;

    mFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            List<T> list = (List<T>) results.values;

            if (results.count == 0) {
                resetData();
            } else {
                mDataItems = list;
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                results.values = mOrigDataItems;
                results.count = mOrigDataItems.size();
            } else {

                List<T> filter =
                        funDapterFilter.filter(constraint.toString(), mOrigDataItems);

                results.count = filter.size();
                results.values = filter;

            }

            return results;
          }
      };
  }

  public void resetData() {
      mDataItems = mOrigDataItems;
     }

  }
```

It has been a week that I'm struggling with this, I would be so grateful if you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView` there is nothing wrong in your code in `getView` block but i don't know the problem

Comment: I know less about RecyclerView  but , can you explain more about why should I use it instead of Listview and what do i achieve if I do it ? cause I have to change a lot of things then

Comment: Because i was having same issues using list view but that's why